# ADO left join issue

Tags: sql, vb6, ado

I want to make a LEFT JOIN as follow:

```
sSQL10 = "SELECT workers.WorkerID, Assignements.* From (workers "
sSql11 = "LEFT JOIN Assignements "
sSQL12 = " ON workers.WorkerID = Assignements.WorkerID) WHERE Assignements.opendate111=#" & Me.OpenDate & "#"
sSQL = sSQL10 & sSql11 & sSQL12
rs_worker.Open sSQL, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
With rs_worker
    Do While Not .EOF
        MsgBox .Fields("WorkerID").value
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

The msgbox return an error although rs_worker has one record with a WorkerID value.

```
MsgBox .Fields(1).value
```

does return a value and .field(1).name appears as **assignements.WorkerID** while I was expecting to be able to reference it as **rs_worker!WorkerID**

Comment: Try .Fields(0).value    The index starts from 0

Comment: Say: "return error" mean nothing! You have to specific: 1) Type of error 2) Line where error.

Answer (score 1):

Field(1) is not `workers.WorkerID`, since it is base 0. In the future do not use index when accessing fields. Use `Fields.Items("FieldNameHere").Value`.

Pls look at [Effecient way to access field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530422/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-access-the-value-of-a-field-in-an-ado-recordse)

Answer (score 0):

```
rs_worker.Open sSQL, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
With rs_worker
    If NOT.BOF Then
        .MoveFirst
        Do While Not .EOF
            MsgBox .Fields(0).value
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    Else
        msgbox "no records found"

    End If
End With
```